# Count the number of row with Like condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Sql Table like :

```
-----------------
id person | entity
------------------
1 | A/B
2 | A/B/C
3 | A/B/C
4 | A/B/D
5 | A/B/C
```

I wanna calculate number of persons having the same entity + who have the same mother entity

Example :

```
-----------------
entity | count
------------------
A/B | 5
A/B/C | 3
A/B/D | 1
```

How can I do it with SQL request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer, have a correlated sub-query that counts similar entities:

```
select distinct t1.entity, (select count(*)
                            from tablename t2 
                            where t2.entity like concat(t1.entity,'%')) 
from tablename t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`, like:

```
SELECT count(*),'A/B' FROM myTable WHERE entity  like '%A/B%'
UNION
SELECT count(*),'A/B/C' FROM myTable WHERE entity  like '%A/B/C%'
UNION
.... --leave to you to complete as an exercise
```

You have to complete the last clause

Comment: what if there are hundrends of different values of entity

Comment: @Rams, Then UNION would not have been an appropriate solution